# Нужен ли знак препинания после «сотрудникам»?

Tags: пунктуация

Просьба к сотрудникам не оставлять пищевые отходы на рабочих местах, а также производить вынос бумажного мусора самостоятельно.

Answer (score 2):

Возможны варианты:

1) *Просьба к сотрудникам не оставлять пищевые отходы на рабочих местах, а также производить вынос бумажного мусора самостоятельно. Несогласованное определение, выраженное инфинитивом: просьба (какая?) не оставлять, а также производить вынос.*

В справочнике Лопатина:

> § 60. **Несогласованные определения, выраженные инфинитивом, обычно не
>   обособляются, они образуют вместе с именем существительным
>   словосочетание: желание учиться, приказ выехать, идея создать общество
>   милосердия, мечта заняться искусством, распоряжение выполнить задание.**
>   Например: *Я дал команду залечь и приступить к изучению оборонительной
>   системы противника (Зл.); Нужно иметь мужество признать и свою неудачу
>   (Копт.); Кирилл Иванович ощущал в себе желание повторять каждое слово
>   по нескольку раз, но почему-то боялся делать это (М. Г.).*

2) *Просьба к сотрудникам -  не оставлять пищевые отходы на рабочих местах, а также производить вынос бумажного мусора самостоятельно.*

Там же:

> **Инфинитив в
>   качестве определения отделяется от определяемого слова знаком тире,
>   если определяемое имя уже имеет при себе определение. Инфинитивное
>   определение в таком случае приобретает смысл дополнительного
>   разъяснения (возможна вставка слов а именно):** *Сбывалась старая
>   вихровская мечта — еще раз прикоснуться щекой к суховатой, вскормившей
>   его груди (Леон.).* **Обособленные инфинитивные определения,
>   распространенные и нераспространенные, располагаются в конце
>   предложения:** *— Я наложу на всех одну обязанность — творить (М. Г.); А
>   почему бы вам, скажем, не задаться простой и очень важной целью —
>   сэкономить средства, выделенные государством вашей школе (газ.)*.

https://orfhographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119

Так что **обычно несогласованные определения, выраженные инфинитивом, не обособляются**, но если учесть, что стоят определения в конце предложения и перед ними можно поставить "а именно", то можно поставить тире. На Ваш выбор. А вот двоеточие нельзя, это не обобщающее слово, если бы слово просьба было во множественном числе, его можно было бы счесть обобщающим, тогда бы и двоеточие было б возможно

Comment: Все примеры из источников относятся к случаю, когда "просьба" с её содержанием в форме определительного оборота выступает членом _полного_ предложения. В нашем же случае отсутствие знака препинания превращает предложение в назывное (элемент списка или заголовок, в то время как по смыслу _просьба к сотрудникам = просим сотрудников_), а постановка тире вызывает вопрос об основании для замены им двоеточия (после которого обычно раскрывается содержание). "Грамота" называет в подобном случае двоеточие **возможным**, но не обязательным: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=302541

Comment: P.S. Интересно было бы найти серьёзный источник с подобным нашему примером.

Comment: Вы правы, двоеточие возможно, если считать предложение БСП, тогда " Просьба к сотрудникам " будет неполным предложением (= у нас есть просьба, мы просим). Я что-то зациклилась на простом предложении.